# React Testing Library: Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="task"]

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-testing-library, redux-toolkit

I am trying to test a `Task` component which renders after a form is submitted. I am using `redux-toolkit`, but the `data-testid="task"` which is the `Task` component never gets rendered in the test DOM.

When I run the test I get:

> FAIL  src/App/App.test.jsx > when form is submitted a new task is
> rendered TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element by:
> [data-testid="task"]

When I use `screen.debug()` I see that the `Task` component never renders in the test DOM, it only renders:

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <main>
      <section class="container">
        <form
          action=""
          class="css-qkao1d"
          data-testid="main-form"
        >
          <input
            class="css-1cknma0-Form"
            data-testid="text-input"
            name="task"
            placeholder="Write your task here..."
            type="text"
            value=""
          />
          <button
            class="css-1nkx97o"
            data-testid="add-btn"
            type="submit"
          >
            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus" />
          </button>
        </form>
        <section data-testid="list" />
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

```
import './App.css'
import Form from '../Components/Form/Form'
import List from '../Components/List/List'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { store } from './store'

function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <main>
        <section className='container'>
          <Form />
          <List />
        </section>
      </main>
    </Provider>
  )
}

export default App
```

```
/** @jsxImportSource @emotion/react */
import { css } from "@emotion/react";
import { addTask } from "../../redux/tasksSlice";
import {
  MyButton,
  MyForm
} from "../../styles";
import { useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import { useState } from "react";
import generateUniqueId from '../../utils';

export default function Form() {
  const [task, setTask] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleSubmit = (e) => { 
    e.preventDefault();
    const newTask = {
      id: generateUniqueId(),
      myTask: task,
    };
    if (newTask.myTask) {
      dispatch(addTask(newTask));
    } else {
      return;
    }
    setTask("");
  }

  return (
    <MyForm
      action=""
      onSubmit={handleSubmit}
      data-testid="main-form"
    >
      <input 
        type="text" 
        placeholder="Write your task here..." 
        css={css`
          flex: 5;
        `}
        name="task"
        value={task}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setTask(e.target.value)
        }}
        data-testid="text-input"
      />
      <MyButton 
        type="submit"
        data-testid="add-btn"
      > 
        <i className="fa-solid fa-plus"></i>
      </MyButton>
    </MyForm>
  )
}
```

```
import { selectTasksArray } from "../../redux/tasksSlice";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import Task from "../Task/Task";

export default function List() {
  const tasks = useSelector(selectTasksArray);
  console.log(tasks)
  return (
    <section data-testid="list">
      {tasks && (
        tasks.map(task => {
          const { id, myTask } = task;
          return (
            <Task id={id} myTask={myTask} key={id} />
          )
        })
      )}
    </section>
  )
}
```

```
import { useState } from "react"
import { MyButton, MyTask, TaskButtons } from "../../styles";
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { editTask, removeTask } from "../../redux/tasksSlice";
import { MyForm } from "../../styles";

export default function Task({ myTask, id }) {
  const [edit, setEdit] = useState(false);
  const [newTaskValue, setNewTaskValue] = useState("");
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const handleThoughtRemoval = (id) => {
    dispatch(removeTask(id))
  }

  const handleEdit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    dispatch(editTask({ id, newTaskValue }));
    setNewTaskValue("");
    toggleSetEdit();
  };

  const toggleSetEdit = () => {
    setEdit(false);
  }

  return (
    <MyTask className="task" key={id} data-testid="task">
      {!edit && (<p>{myTask}</p>)}

      {edit ? (
        <MyForm onSubmit={(e) => handleEdit(e)}>
          <input
            type="text"
            value={newTaskValue}
            onChange={(e) => setNewTaskValue(e.target.value)}
            placeholder="rename task..."
          />
          <MyButton
            type="submit"
            data-testid="edit-completed-btn"
          >
            <i className="fa-solid fa-check"></i>
          </MyButton>
        </MyForm>
      ) : (
        <TaskButtons>
          <MyButton
            data-testid="edit-btn"
            onClick={() => {
              setEdit(true)
            }}
          >
            <i className="fa-solid fa-pen-to-square"></i>
          </MyButton>
          <MyButton
            onClick={() => handleThoughtRemoval(id)}
            data-testid="remove-btn"
          >
            <i className="fa-solid fa-trash"></i>
          </MyButton>
        </TaskButtons>
      )}
    </MyTask> 
  )
}
```

```
import { render , screen, act, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import App from "./App";
import userEvent from "@testing-library/user-event";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createTestStore } from '../test/testStore';

test("App is rendering along with form and list", () => { 
  render(<App />);

  const mainForm = screen.getByTestId("main-form");
  const list = screen.getByTestId("list");

  expect(mainForm).toBeInTheDocument();
  expect(list).toBeInTheDocument();
});

test("when form is submitted a new task is rendered", async () => { 
  //provide initial tasks to the Redux store
  const initialTasks = [{ id: 1, myTask: "Initial task" }];
  const store = createTestStore({ tasks: initialTasks });

  render (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );

  const input = screen.getByTestId("text-input");
  const addBtn = screen.getByTestId("add-btn");

  act(() => {
    userEvent.type(input, "new task");
    userEvent.click(addBtn);
  })

  const newTask = await screen.findByTestId("task");
  expect(newTask).toBeInTheDocument();
});
```

```js
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

const tasksArraySlice = createSlice({
  name: "tasksArray",
  initialState: [],
  reducers: {
    addTask: (state, action) => {
      const newTask = action.payload;
      return [...state, newTask];
    },
    removeTask: (state, action) => { 
      return state.filter(task => task.id !== action.payload)
    },
    editTask: (state, action) => { 
      const { id, newTaskValue } = action.payload;
      state.map(task => {
        if (task.id === id) {
          return task["myTask"] = newTaskValue; 
        }
      })
    }
  },
});

export const tasksArrayReducer = tasksArraySlice.reducer;
export const {
  addTask,
  removeTask,
  editTask
} = tasksArraySlice.actions;
export const selectTasksArray = state => state.tasksArray;
```

```js
/// <reference types="vitest" />
/// <reference types="vite/client" />

import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import react from '@vitejs/plugin-react'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [react()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: "jsdom",
    setupFiles: "./src/test/setup.js",
    css: true
  }
})
```

```
setup.js: import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
```

```js
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { tasksArrayReducer } from '../redux/tasksSlice';

export const createTestStore = (initialState) => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: {
      tasksArray: tasksArrayReducer,
    },
    preloadedState: initialState,
  });
};
```

```js
export default function generateUniqueId() {
  const timestamp = Date.now().toString(36); // Convert timestamp to base 36 string
  const randomNum = Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 5); // Generate a random number and extract a substring
  const uniqueId = timestamp + randomNum; // Combine the timestamp and random number to create a unique ID
  return uniqueId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you closely inspect the debug output you can see that the `data-testid="list"` list section is empty.

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <main>
      <section class="container">
        <form
          action=""
          class="css-qkao1d"
          data-testid="main-form"
        >
          <input
            class="css-1cknma0-Form"
            data-testid="text-input"
            name="task"
            placeholder="Write your task here..."
            type="text"
            value=""
          />
          <button
            class="css-1nkx97o"
            data-testid="add-btn"
            type="submit"
          >
            <i class="fa-solid fa-plus" />
          </button>
        </form>
        <section data-testid="list" /> // <-- empty!
      </section>
    </main>
  </div>
</body>
```

If you are providing state and the selected `tasks` state is a defined, non-empty array, then ***something*** should have rendered into the section.

```
test("when form is submitted a new task is rendered", async () => { 
  //provide initial tasks to the Redux store
  const initialTasks = [{ id: 1, myTask: "Initial task" }];
  const store = createTestStore({ tasks: initialTasks }); // <-- defined, non-empty array

  render (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  );

  ...
});
```

```
export default function List() {
  const tasks = useSelector(selectTasksArray);

  return (
    <section data-testid="list">
      {tasks && (
        tasks.map(task => { // <-- returns values if defined and non-empty
          const { id, myTask } = task;
          return (
            <Task id={id} myTask={myTask} key={id} />
          )
        })
      )}
    </section>
  );
}
```

Note, however, that the test state used to hydrate the `store` in the unit test is `state.tasks` and compare/contrast this to the `selectTasksArray` selector function that is selecting `state.tasksArray` and the state tree formed by the reducer.

```js
export const selectTasksArray = state => state.tasksArray;
```

```js
export const createTestStore = (initialState) => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: {
      tasksArray: tasksArrayReducer, // <-- state.tasksArray
    },
    preloadedState: initialState,
  });
};
```

In other words, `tasks` in the `List` component is undefined or the initial empty array state, so nothing is mapped and the empty `<section data-testid="list" />` JSX is returned.

Configure the initial state to match the state tree and what is selected:

```
const tasksArray = [{ id: 1, myTask: "Initial task" }];
const store = createTestStore({ tasksArray });
```

From here the list section `<section data-testid="list">....</section>` should be populated with tasks, each with a `data-testid="task"` attribute that should be targetable.

The next issue I see here is just a logical error where the test is selecting the ***first*** task element with `data-testid="task"` and asserting the new task was added... but the new task was added to the ***end*** of the tasks array, so you may want to update the test to do something like asserting the tasks array is one longer, or targeting/selecting the last task and asserting the rendered output matches that which was updated to the store.